# JobHeldAdmin Status on Slurm when submitting Snakemake pipeline

Tags: slurm, snakemake

when submitting to Slurm using the following

```
snakemake --cluster "sbatch --mem-per-cpu=16G --ntasks=4 --mail-type=ALL --partition=normal_q --time=48:00:00 --nice=100000" --jobs=100 --use-conda
```

some of my jobs get "JobHeldAdmin"-Status. Does anyone have an idea why this is and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Which version of Slurm is this?

Comment: The version of Slurm is 19.05.4.

Comment: [squeue](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) indicates that is due to "The job is held by a system administrator."  Ask your sysadmins why they are holding, could be updates pending or maybe they want to discuss your jobs.

Comment: jobs are not held by Admin(actively). When job state can not be released, slurm put them it that state (JobHeldAdmin). We tried to submit jobs with less priority, so that slurm does not put job into that state. Did not help.

Comment: I am not really answering the question, but we use `drmaa` for submitting snakemake jobs with slurm. https://github.com/natefoo/slurm-drmaa